# how to get domain name of an IP address in c++

Tags: c++

How can I get domain name for an IP address in C++? There are sites available in online to do that. But I need to find out it in C++ for my application. Hopefully there are APIs to do that. I found there are ways available to get IP address from domain name when I googled. Looking for the reverse of that..

Comment: You are looking for Reverse DNS lookup. Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend on a particular networking library you use. If you have a way to determine the IP from a name, then you basically use the same way, only look up for name `4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa` to figure out what's the name for the IP address `1.2.3.4` (note the reversed order in the name). Some libraries will allow you to do that automatically without bothering with making up that weird name.

In Qt, for example, you could do something like this:

```
printf("%s\n", qPrintable(QHostInfo::fromName("188.35.142.38").hostName()));
```

This prints `cache.google.com`.

But since you don't specify which library you use, it's hard to say more. You just need to read its documentation to figure out how to do reverse DNS lookups there. It's often performed by the same function like in the example above (`fromName` accepts both addresses and names).